# Select subdocument where

Tags: javascript, mongodb

This is probably a noobish question, however I have spent quite some time on it now.

So this is my structure, highly minimized:

```
{
  name : 'Some dude', 
  deck : [{
    name : 'Awesome card',
    value : 30
  },
  {
    name : 'another awesome card',
    value: 50
  }]
}
```

I want to select from all cards in the deck, where name == 'Awesome card', returning this

```
{
  name : 'Some dude', 
  deck : [{
    name : 'Awesome card',
    value : 30
  }]
}
```

been trying loads of commands like

> db.heroes.find({name : "Some dude"}, {'deck' : 1, 'deck.name' : 'Awesome card})

How should I query this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `$` position operator which identifies the index of the matched `deck` array element in your field selection:

```
db.heroes.find(
    {name : "Some dude", 'deck.name' : 'Awesome card'}, 
    {_id: 0, name: 1, 'deck.$.name': 1}
);
```

Comment: You changed the query part of the find.   On given example it returns the same document, but on different data it would not.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Right, it does assume that `name: 'Some dude'` uniquely identifies the document.

Comment: It will not return a document if name matches, but such named card does not exist. Just wanted to make it clear to OP that the query part is not the same.

Answer (score 4):

Use $elemMatch projection:

```
db.heroes.find({name : "Some dude"}, {'deck' : {$elemMatch:{name:'Awesome card}}})
```

See docs [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/elemMatch/).

Comment: This does it aswell, maybe enven more cleaner? Atleast i want to thank you for your answer aswell :-)

Comment: do note that technically the other answer changes your query - I don't know if it's guaranteed that 'Awesome card' exists in the decks you want to have returned.

Answer (score -2):

```
deck = deck.filter(function (card) { return card.name === 'Awesome card' });
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: I am not the downvoter but this question is tagged with mongodb. Your function merely filters values from an array, it doesn't accomplish the goal of the question which is to return information from mongodb